# How to find center points of DBSCAN clusrering in sklearn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, dbscan

How to find the centre point of clusters of `DBSCAN` clustering algorithm in `sklearn`.

Comment: DBSCAN is a density based clustering technique so it doesnt have any notion of centers of clusters as in KMeans. Please describe in detail as to what you want to do. You can obviously find the centroids of clusters found from the DBSCAN after getting all the samples in a cluster and then calculating their mean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DBSCAN doesn't have centers.

You can compute then yourself, but they may be outside of the cluster if it is not convex.